# td size affecting other tds in other rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that the first row is 2 cells,
the second is 3.
the very first cell ([0,0]) is a text box, and all the other are buttons.
for this code:

```
var tr0 = document.createElement('TR'); //the first row
table.appendChild(tr);

var td0 = document.createElement('TD');
tr1.appendChild(td0);
var textbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
textbox.setAttribute('TYPE', 'text');
td0.appendChild(textbox);

var td1= document.createElement('TD');
tr0.appendChild(td1);
var clear = document.createElement('INPUT');
clear.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button');
clear.setAttribute('VALUE', 'C');
td1.appendChild(clear);

var tr1 = document.createElement('TR'); //the second row
table.appendChild(tr1);

var td1_0 = document.createElement('TD');
tr1.appendChild(td1_0);
var one = document.createElement('INPUT');
one.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button');
one.value='1';
td1_0.appendChild(one);


var td1_1 = document.createElement('TD');
tr1.appendChild(td1_1);
var two = document.createElement('INPUT');
two.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button');
two.value='2';
td1_1.appendChild(two);

var td1_2 = document.createElement('TD');
tr1.appendChild(td1_2);
var three = document.createElement('INPUT');
three.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button'); 
three.value='3';
td1_2.appendChild(three);
```

i get : [image: the table]

I want to know the reason and how to fix it in javascript, can't use JQuery and it has to be in a js file. tnx in advance!

Comment: What is it you're expecting. This is exactly how an HTML table renders.  Columns are always the same width. Your textbox is wide, making the first column wide and will affect the first column of the second row.

Comment: @Robbert, i can see that, but how can i solve this? i want that '1' will be next to '2' and '3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything side by side, you don't need to create new table cells for each input. Just put each button in the same cell.

```
var tr0 = document.createElement('TR'); //the first row
table.appendChild(tr0);

var td0 = document.createElement('TD');
tr0.appendChild(td0);
var textbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
textbox.setAttribute('TYPE', 'text');
td0.appendChild(textbox);

var clear = document.createElement('INPUT');
clear.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button');
clear.setAttribute('VALUE', 'C');
td0.appendChild(clear);

var tr1 = document.createElement('TR'); //the second row
table.appendChild(tr1);

var td1 = document.createElement('TD');
tr1.appendChild(td1);
var one = document.createElement('INPUT');
one.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button');
one.value='1';
td1.appendChild(one);


var two = document.createElement('INPUT');
two.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button');
two.value='2';
td1.appendChild(two);

var three = document.createElement('INPUT');
three.setAttribute('TYPE', 'button'); 
three.value='3';
td1.appendChild(three);
```

You'll notice that there are now just two TD elements (td0 and td1), and your input elements (both the textbox and the buttons) are appended to one or the other.  You could also put these into paragraph of div elements instead of a table, but that's up to you :)

For example

```
var div0 = document.createElement('div'); //the first row
var textbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
textbox.setAttribute('TYPE', 'text');
div0.appendChild(textbox);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is caused by the difference of numbers of columns of each row.

`colspan` attribute joins two or more columns to one.

See the difference here: https://jsfiddle.net/80LLkr9g/1/.

I suppose your code should be like:

```
var td0 = document.createElement('TD');
td0.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
tr1.appendChild(td0);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thank you for your indication. I rewrited the answer.

Comment: @KazmaArakaki thanks, but it's not the problem. the problem is that the column has the same width for all of it cells, and the first cell in the column define the size for the rest of the column..